# Horizontal scroll content

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

i am trying to do a website in wich there is a section where the content has to scroll horizontally as you click on the menu buttons, it also has direction nav, i think i got it with the direction nav but i can not figure it out on how to track the position of my div's in order to move them every time i do click on them. i am trying to use offset(); with jquery but cannot making work. i will appreciate if someone could help me to make my way to achieve this. ill leave you some code and a js fiddle so you guys can see what i have so far.

html code:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li id="1" class="active-state">1</li>
        <li id="2">2</li>
        <li id="3">3</li>
        <li id="4">4</li>
        <li id="5">5</li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<section id="content">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="content" id="yellow"></div>
        <div class="content" id="blue"></div>
        <div class="content" id="red"></div>
        <div class="content" id="purple"></div>
        <div class="content" id="green"></div>
    </div>
</section>
<ul id="directionNav">
    <li id="left">left</li>
    <li id="right">right</li>
</ul>
```

jquery code to do horizontal scroll:

```
$("#3").on("click", horizontalScroll);
$("#4").on("click", horizontalScroll2);

function horizontalScroll() {
console.log($("#3").offset().left);
$("#wrapper").animate({
    right: ($("#4").offset().left -1200)
});
console.log("clicked");
}

function horizontalScroll2() {
console.log($("#4").offset().left);
$("#wrapper").animate({
    right: ($("#4").offset().left -1200)
});
console.log("clicked");
}
```

here is the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/xtatanx/DY3k3/

thank you very much to all!

Comment: I think there are loads of plugin available for this purpose already. try http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are coding to much!

Give attribute to your HTML tag with the page he is linked on:

```
<li frame='1' class='nav'>page 1</li>
```

Then add a signle function on all `.nav` that will go to the page called in the attribut:

```
function changeFrame(){
    $('#wrapper').animate({left : $(this).attr('frame')*-600});
    $('.active-state').removeClass('active-state')
    $(this).addClass('active-state')
}
```

For your next/prev link, just check wich page you currently are and add/substract 1. I did it in 2 function for a cleaner code.

On click it check wich on is clicked:

```
function navigFrame(){
    switch(this.id){
        case 'left' : doNavig(-1); break;
        case 'right' : doNavig(1); break;
    }
}
```

And here's the code of `onNavig` :

```
function doNavig(direction){
    var newPage = parseInt($('.active-state').attr('frame'))+direction;
    if(newPage < $('.nav').length && newPage >= 0){
        $('#wrapper').animate({left : newPage*-600});
        $('.active-state').removeClass('active-state')
        $('.nav:nth-child('+String(newPage + 1)+')').addClass('active-state')
    }
}
```

Code could be more optimised, but i want you to do some work :)

Here's the complete code : http://jsfiddle.net/DY3k3/2/

Comment: well i am just learning javascript and jquery thats why i am coding so much :p but i appreciate your help ill study the code in order to understand all what you did! thank you very much! so usefull!

Comment: It was my pleasure. If you need help to understand what i did (function or whatever) feel free to ask here.

Comment: i actually have 1 question, i still don't understand how it animates -600 in one direction, but when it reach its position it should animate +600 instead of -600 right? how do u achieve that with just than few lines

Comment: Its -600 (that's the negative value of the width of your cell) * attr "frame" witch contain a number (check html node). Since I animated left position, it need to be negative, else it would go the other side.

Comment: yeah i understand, but when you press the button 5 it reaches the position and when you press 1 again its supposed to go +600 instead of -600? :/ ahahah

Comment: No, because I am not adding some value, im change it. See when you click on btn 5, it do 4*-600 witch = -2400. If you check with firebug of chrome inspector, you will see `style='left:-2400px'`. When you click on #1, it do 0*-600 = 0 and travel from the last position (-2400) to the new pos (0). Keep an eye on the wrapper div in the inspector, you will see what animate really do on the div : changing style value every x millisecond!

Comment: hey thank you very much! its always really good to see someone else code....this is going to help me improve a lot! thanks again!